# KivyMD callback(self,instance) example

Tags: python, callback, kivy, kivy-language

I am using a floating action button speed dial in kivymd. I have added the data dictionary and want to add separate functions to all the sub buttons. For that I have to use `callback`. Can anyone tell me by an example how do I do it?
Kv code:

```
MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
    callback: app.callback
    data:app.data
```

Python code:

```
class Example(MDApp):
    data = {
        'language-python': 'Python',
        'language-php': 'PHP',
        'language-cpp': 'C++',
    }

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
```

Update
I followed up and found that callback:app.callback will be required to call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/index.html#kivymd.uix.button.MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial.callback), you can just add a `callback` method to your `App`, like this:

```
class Example(MDApp):
    data = {
        'language-python': 'Python',
        'language-php': 'PHP',
        'language-cpp': 'C++',
    }

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def callback(self, instance):
        print(instance.icon)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you give me more info about the usage of callback() ? How do I add separate functions to separate sub buttons stored in data dict

Comment: The only way that I am aware of is to put logic in the `callback` to determine which function you want to call. You can base that on the `instance` that is passed to `callback`.